Android: playing an insecure audio stream
I am building an Android app with Ionic Angular and Capacitor. The app lists radio streams and plays them. Except that with streams which use http:// unsecure requests, the app fails to play the unsecure streams. I have no control over the stream, so I should find a way to play unsecure streams. Probably there is a setting in the AndroidManifest.xml file that should allow this, but I haven't been able to find information on it.  Anyone any ideas?
E/Capacitor/Console: File: https://localhost/app/tabs/player - Line 0 - Msg: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://localhost/app/tabs/player' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure audio file 'http://stream.xxx.xx/xxxxx'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.


It doesn't have any effect...

I just noticed that by insecure you do not mean plain text http, instead you are searching for a way to disable certificate checking for an https connection because your server doesn't use a valid https certificate. I would recommend to reformulate your question and use proper tags to attract the people who know how to solve this problem with ionic thing, I only know how to solve it in real Android apps.
